# SQL. Don't show row if column has no value

Tags: sql, database

List authors who have 'e' as the 4th letter in first name or last name, and have a pseudonym.

`select * from authors
where last_name like '___e%' or first_name like '___e%' and  pseudonym is not null and pseudonym <> ' ';`

[The output still show the row where pseudonym are null (picture)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zR8wV.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

```
select *
from authors
where (last_name like '___e%' or first_name like '___e%') and
      trim(pseudonym) is not null;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need parentheses:

```
select *
from authors
where (last_name like '___e%' or first_name like '___e%') and
      pseudonym is not null and
      pseudonym <> ' ';
```

If you are learning SQL, then use parentheses whenever your conditions have more than one logical operator (such as (`AND`) and (`OR`)).

The comparison `is not null` is redundant.  I would recommend that you leave it in anyway, just to be explicit about the conditions.